Is $M \dot{+} N$ closed?
Let $X := \ell^{p}(\mathbb{N})$ and $M := \{a ∈ X|a_{2n} = 0\}$, $N := \{b ∈ X \ |\ n\cdot b_{2n} = b_{2n−1}\}$.
Question: Is $M ∔ N$ closed?
My approach: Denote by $A = \{(a_j)_{j=1}^{\infty} \in l^{p}(\mathbb{N}) \ | \ \text{there are finitely many } a_j \text{ which are non-zero}\}$ the set of all sequences which have compact support.
Now, let $a \in \ell^{p}(\mathbb{N})$ be arbitrary and define $\tilde{a}^{j} := (a_1, a_2, \cdots, a_j, 0, 0, \cdots)$ with $j \in \mathbb{N}$ and where we use the first $j$ entries of our element $a$. Clearly we have that $\tilde{a}^{j} \in A$ for all $j \in \mathbb{N}$.
It's now easy to see that
$$\lVert{a - \tilde{a}^{j}}\rVert_p^{p} = \sum_{k = j+1}^{\infty}|a_k|^p = C < \infty$$
since $a \in \ell^{p}(\mathbb{N})$. This means that we can construct for any arbitrary $\varepsilon > 0$ and any arbitrary $a \in \ell^{p}(\mathbb{N})$ an element $\tilde{a}^{j} \in A$ such that the distance between $a$ and $\tilde{a}^{j}$ can be made smaller than $\varepsilon$ (= i.e. arbitrarily small).
To my understanding, this is the definition of a dense set, so we can conclude that $A$ is dense in $\ell^{p}(\mathbb{N})$.
I would now like to show that $A \subseteq M \dot{+} N$ because if that was the case, then $\ell^{p}(\mathbb{N}) = \overline{A} \subseteq \overline{M \dot{+} N}$. I am a little bit struggling with that part.
So, if $M \dot{+} N$ was closed, then we would have $\overline{M \dot{+} N} = M \dot{+} N$ and therefore $\ell^{p}(\mathbb{N}) = M \dot{+} N$ which is clearly not the case. Therefore $M \dot{+} N$ is not closed.
Could anybody tell me if my approach is correct and maybe help me with polishing the proof? Any help and advice is appreciated! :-)

What does the addition with the dot on it indicate? Sorry if I’m not too familiar with your notation.

Hi! Sorry for not explaining that in the post. The dot indicates that $M \cap N = {0}$.

This isn’t a whole answer so I’ll post it as a comment. Logically, everything you have said is sound. I’d say that to complete the proof you still need the $A\subseteq M+N$ claim and to give an explicitly example of an element in $l^p$ not in $M+N$.

For $1<p<\infty$ consider $a_n={1\over n}.$ We claim that $a\notin M+N.$ Assume by contradiction that $a=b+c,$ where $b\in M$ and $c\in N.$ Hence $b_{2n}=0.$ Thus ${1\over 2n}=a_{2n}=c_{2n}.$ On the other hand $c_{2n-1}=nc_{2n}={1\over 2}.$ Thus $c\notin \ell^p,$ a contradiction.
The space $M+N$ contains every element of the standard basis $e_n.$ Indeed $e_{2n-1}\in M$ and $e_{2n}+ne_{2n-1}\in N.$ Hence $e_{2n}=-ne_{2n-1}+[e_{2n}+ne_{2n-1}]\in M+N.$ Thus $M+N$ is dense in $\ell^p.$ As $M+N\subsetneq \ell^p,$ it cannot be closed.
For $p=1$ we may take $a_n={1\over n^2}.$ Then $c_{2n-1}={1\over 2n}.$ Hence $c\notin \ell^1.$
For $1<p<\infty$ consider $a_n={1\over n}.$ We claim that $a\notin M+N.$ Assume by contradiction that $a=b+c,$ where $b\in M$ and $c\in N.$ Hence $b_{2n}=0.$ Thus ${1\over 2n}=a_{2n}=c_{2n}.$ On the other hand $c_{2n-1}=nc_{2n}={1\over 2}.$ Thus $c\notin \ell^p,$ a contradiction.
The space $M+N$ contains every element of the standard basis $e_n.$ Indeed $e_{2n-1}\in M$ and $e_{2n}+ne_{2n-1}\in N.$ Hence $e_{2n}=-ne_{2n-1}+[e_{2n}+ne_{2n-1}]\in M+N.$ Thus $M+N$ is dense in $\ell^p.$ As $M+N\subsetneq \ell^p,$ it cannot be closed.
For $p=1$ we may take $a_n={1\over n^2}.$ Then $c_{2n-1}={1\over 2n}.$ Hence $c\notin \ell^1.$
For $p=\infty$ the closure of $M+N$ contains all the sequences of the subspace $c_0$ consisting of $a$ such that $a_n\to 0,$ as the linear span of $\{e_n\} $ is contained in $M+N$ and is dense in $ c_0.$  On the other hand $M+N$ consists of all sequences $a$ such that $na_{2n}$ is bounded. So $a_{n}={1\over \sqrt{n}}$ does not belong to $M+N,$ but belongs to the closure of $M+N.$

For $c=e_{2n}+ne_{2n-1}$ we have $c_{k}=0$ when $k\neq 2n$ and $k\neq 2n-1.$ In particular $c_{2m-1}=c_{2m}=0$ for $m\neq n.$ On the other hand $c_{2n}=1$ while $c_{2n-1}=n=nc_{2n}.$
